# Censor word from a string

Tags: java, string, replace, char

I really need help with this code. I need to create a code that censor with "####" every word that starts with a "p" and ends wit an "r" and every word that starts with an "h" and contains an "o". I already managed to do that but the problem is that it only puts one "#" symbol, and I want to put as many # as there are letters.

like this "home" >>>>> "####" or "hologram" "########".

I know I need to read every character but I don't know how. Please help.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your blog");
    String line = sc.nextLine();        
    String[] word = line.split(" ");                    
    for(String s: word){             
            if(s.startsWith("p") && s.endsWith("r")){  

                s = s.replace(s, "#");
            }
            if(s.startsWith("h") && s.contains("o")){
                s = s.replace(s, "#");                

            }  


        System.out.print(s + " ");
    }
    }
```

Comment: `s=s.replaceAll(".", "#");` - `replaceAll` uses regex syntax where `.` represents any single character (except line separator)

Comment: @Pshemo isn't OP is asking bit more than what you marked as duplicate? I believe OP wants conditional substitution.

Comment: @Saleem OP already managed to write proper conditions. Only problem left was "*...it only puts **one** "#" symbol, and I want to put as many # as there are letters.*" which is similar to what duplicate question is about.

Comment: @Pshemo, yes you are correct!